# Rx.Observable.fromPromise not working with Redux-Observable Epics

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, reactive-programming, redux-observable

I am currently working on a react native app and trying to use [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) for middleware with redux.

For simplicity, I'm only including the epic that contains a promise and not dilute it with networking code.

Here is my unit test against an authentication API that just takes a username, password, and should return the username, password, and authentication token. Again, this should instantly return and have the store contain `AUTHENTICATE` and `AUTHENTICATE_FULFILLED`

```js
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import * as servicesRoot from '../app/services/root'

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(servicesRoot.epics);
const mockStore = configureMockStore([epicMiddleware]);

describe('Session Service', () => {

    let store;

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        epicMiddleware.replaceEpic(servicesRoot.epics)
    });

    describe('Authentication API', () => {
        it('I should receive an authToken', () => {

            let username = 'myUsername'
            let password = 'myPassword'
            const data = { username, password, authToken: 'test_auth_token' }; 

            let action = servicesRoot.actions.authenticate(username, password)
            store.dispatch(action)
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([
              servicesRoot.actions.authenticate(username, password),
              servicesRoot.actions.authenticate_fulfilled(data)
            ]);

        })
    })
})
```

My authentication epic looks like

```js
import Rx from 'rxjs'
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes'
import { authenticate_fulfilled } from './actions'

export const authenticateEpic = action$ => 
    action$.ofType(actionTypes.AUTHENTICATE)
        .mergeMap(action => 
            Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve('test'))
                .map(result => authenticate_fulfilled({ ...action.payload, authToken: 'test_auth_token'}))
        )
```

Note: my `servicesRoot.actions.authenticate` returns the action to use that contains the `AUTHENTICATE` type, and `authenticate_fulfilled` returns another `AUTHENTICATE_FULFILLED` action.

My output from the unit test is

```
 FAIL  __tests__/api.js
  ● Session Service › Authentication API › I should receive an authToken

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      [{"payload": {"password": "myPassword", "username": "myUsername"}, "type": "AUTHENTICATE"}, {"payload": {"authToken": "test_auth_token", "password": "myPassword", "username": "myUsername"}, "type": "AUTHENTICATE_FULFILLED"}]
    Received:
      [{"payload": {"password": "myPassword", "username": "myUsername"}, "type": "AUTHENTICATE"}]

    Difference:

    - Expected
    + Received

    @@ -4,14 +4,6 @@
           "password": "myPassword",
           "username": "myUsername",
         },
         "type": "AUTHENTICATE",
       },
    -  Object {
    -    "payload": Object {
    -      "authToken": "test_auth_token",
    -      "password": "myPassword",
    -      "username": "myUsername",
    -    },
    -    "type": "AUTHENTICATE_FULFILLED",
    -  },
     ]

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/api.js:36:28)

  Session Service
    Authentication API
      ✕ I should receive an authToken (44ms)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.15s
Ran all test suites matching /api/.
```

My test passes if I change the epic to

```js
export const authenticateEpic = action$ => 
    action$.ofType(actionTypes.AUTHENTICATE)
        .mergeMap(action => 
            Rx.Observable.of('test')
                .map(result => authenticate_fulfilled({ ...action.payload, authToken: 'test_auth_token'}))
        )
```

I'm not sure why `fromPromise` is not giving the behavior I'm expecting. I narrowed it down to an issue with the promise. Essentially this will be a result from a network request, and then be handled accordingly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Promise.resolve` resolves asynchronously, but your test calls `store.getActions()` immediately, so you only see the synchronously dispatched action. The `redux-mock-store` doc has a section on testing [asynchronous actions](http://arnaudbenard.com/redux-mock-store/).